# Excel macro not copying the data into the right cells

Tags: excel, vba

I created a spreadsheet with 5 columns, when the user press enter, it should copy the info to a 2nd spreadsheet.  However the 2nd button is copying the info from the same first column, but I already checked and both buttons have Trade1 and Trade2 macros selected.

Screenshot 1: http://screencast.com/t/zudhZCIQGA3l 
Screenshot 2: http://screencast.com/t/6NyW3gTy8oY

As you can see in SS2, after pressing button 2, its copying the wrong data.

The code is below

```
Sub Trade1()
    Sheets("Trades").Select
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R2C2"
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R3C2"
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R4C2"
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R5C2"
    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R6C2"
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R8C2"
    Range("G2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R7C2"
    Range("H2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R9C2"
    Range("I2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R10C2"
    Range("J2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R11C2"
    Range("K2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R11C2"
    Range("K2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R12C2"
    Range("P2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R13C2"
    Range("Q2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R14C2"
    Range("R2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R15C2"
    Range("S2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R16C2"
    Range("T2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R17C2"
    Range("U2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R18C2"
    Range("V2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R19C2"
    Range("V3").Select
    Sheets("Enter Trade").Select
End Sub

Sub Trade2()
    Sheets("Trades").Select
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R2C3"
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R3C3"
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R4C3"
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R5C3"
    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R6C3"
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R8C3"
    Range("G2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R7C3"
    Range("H2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R9C3"
    Range("I2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R10C3"
    Range("J2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R11C3"
    Range("K2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R11C3"
    Range("K2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R12C3"
    Range("P2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R13C3"
    Range("Q2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R14C3"
    Range("R2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R15C3"
    Range("S2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R16C3"
    Range("T2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R17C3"
    Range("U2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R18C3"
    Range("V2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+'Enter Trade'!R19C3"
    Range("V3").Select
    Sheets("Enter Trade").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: First thing you should note is that you don't need to rely on activeCell, you can use the cell itself. For example: instead of doing "Range("G2").Select  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1..." do Range("G2").FormulaR1C1. Why have you included the VB.NET tag (do you want to convert this into VB.NET)? In any case your code is very confusing (and, for sure, highly-optimisable), could you better explain what you want to accomplish exactly?: it seems like it should be redone from scratch rather than improved. You basically want to convert the columns in the first link into rows with small variations, isn't it?

Comment: Please include the screenshots with your question or upload them to a place that doesn't require JavaScript.

Comment: I dont have experience with macros, so I just recorded it in Excel 2013. I want to copy the contents of every column in a new row in the 2nd spreadheet

Comment: the links have the screenshots. any browser can open those links

Comment: If you want just to convert each column into a row, you can rely on copy/paste-special (transpose). But I do observe small variations between your two snapshots; for example: in the first link "Shares" is located before "Initial Risk", but in the second one this positions are inverted; this is an error or represents the exact behaviour you are looking for?

Comment: I can make them in the same order if needed to make the script simpler, can you please explain how to do that?

Comment: I can send the file if needed, also an error I am seeing is that every new row gets duplicated

Comment: I have written my answer right now. You should put "@" before the nick, otherwise the other person does not know that you are talking with him (unless being in a question created by this other person) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a simple code copying (and transposing) a range between two sheets.

```
Dim fromRange As Range, toRange As Range

Set fromRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A3")
Set toRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

fromRange.Copy
toRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
```

You can call this code recursively (while iterating through all the columns in the original range). Bear in mind that ranges can also be defined through `Cell` and thus:

```
Set fromRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 1))
```

This code is identical to the `Set fromRange` above, although this one might be more helpful when being in a loop. For example:

```
Dim iniRow As Integer, maxRow As Integer, col As Integer, maxCol As Integer

iniRow = 1
maxRow = 20
col = 0
maxCol = 10
Do
   col = col + 1
   Set fromRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iniRow, col), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(maxRow, col))
   Set toRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(col, 1)) 'Assuming that the row in the destination sheet equals the column in the original one
   toRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
Loop While (col < maxCol)
```

Or you might do directly

```
Set fromRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z1000") 
Set toRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
```

But I always prefer to highlight the `Cells` option for newbies just in case.

Comment: @LuisValencia No problem. I have included a new update in my answer right now which you might find useful while iterating through the ranges.